# How to write text inside a rectangle in emacs artist-mode?

Tags: emacs

I am learning artist-mode in emacs and finding it pretty interesting.

I want to create shapes and write text inside them as we can do with other software where one can draw shapes.

However, when I type some characters inside a rectangle, the shape gets distorted. The vertical line gets shifted by some characters.

Please see attached image.
[image]

Is there something I can do to fix it? Or is it a bug in artist-mode. I watched some screencasts and videos and did not remember anyone mentioning anything about this odd behavior.

I am on Mac and my emacs version is

GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0, NS appkit-1504.00 Version 10.12 (Build 16A323))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this before you type text into a rectangle.

1. `C-x h`   (Select the whole buffer.)
2. `M-x untabify <RET>`

This will make you buffer tab free, which should solve the problem when you are typing.

Note that you should **avoid using `backspace`** for deleting text. Move your cursor and overwrite them instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised not to see `overwrite-mode`.  This replaces text at point rather than inserting it.

People have mentioned `untabify` to change tabs to spaces.  Use `whitespace-mode` to see where those tabs (and spaces) are.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround I found for this cases.

1. select **text** mode
2. add the relevant text, RET
3. type **term** RET (here we specify the font)
4. RET (No ARGS for figlet, might also depend upon use-cases)

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit clumsy, but I usually do

1. select text mode
2. press Insert (Ovwrt)
3. add text
4. enter artist mode