# Artist mode drawing characters disorder

Tags: emacs

I was trying out Artist mode for drawings. But I found that although what I saw is totally in order, the file turned out to be chaos.

This is what it appears to be like in artist mode:
[file under artist mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ryp99.png)

But actually the file is like this:
[actual file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCts9.png)

I was using Emacs25 for macOS

Comment: (a) are you using the same font both times? (b) is it a fixed-width font? (c) are there tabs in the file? (d) is `tab-width` the same both times?

Comment: Hi, phils! Thanks for you hint! It helped me a lot! I solved the problem by setting back the tab-width to default, which was 8.

Comment: Once it's looking correct, consider using `C-x h` (or otherwise selecting the text in question) and then `M-x untabify` to eliminate the tabs. If `indent-tabs-mode` is `nil` in a buffer, Emacs won't introduce tabs in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! **untabify** also solve the typing problem in [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41352871/how-to-write-text-inside-a-rectangle-in-emacs-artist-mode)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this problem will occur if you set the tab-width in Emacs. I solved the problem by comment them out.

For example, in my case, I removed these two lines and everything works fine in Artist Mode.

```
(setq default-tab-width 4)
(setq tab-width 4)
```

Comment: Also check out `indent-tabs-mode`.  You might want to do something like `(add-hook 'artist-mode-hook (lambda () (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)))`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem by drawing shapes like that exist in RFC texts like [figure One in this document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8001).

@jpkotta [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976371/artist-mode-drawing-characters-disorder#comment75311260_43977757) guide me to solve it.

First, add this line to emacs config.

`echo "(add-hook 'artist-mode-hook (lambda () (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)))" >> ~/.emacs`

Now draw a shape in emacs with emacs artistic-mode.

Enable artistic mode with

```
M-x artist-mode
```

The shape created with this method retains border and does not deface in all tools I check the `emacs`, `cat`, `vim`, `geany`, `mousepad`.

[image: Screenshot]